# Prove a linear transformation symmetric and positive

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $Ax = (a \cdot x)a+ |a|^2x$. Is $A$ symmetric?  Is it positive?

I know that a matrix is symmetric IFF $(Ax,y) = (x,Ay)$ and positive if $x \cdot Ax > 0$ for all vectors $x \not = 0$.

Comment: Do you know the condition on the principal minors (of some matrix representation of $\;A\;$) for positiveness?

Comment: Is that not what I put in the second line?  If not, then no I do not.

Comment: No, it is not that....and that second line condition should read $\;x^tAx>0\;$

Comment: The $x \cdot Ax > 0$ for all $x \not = 0$ was given as a hint by the professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the usual, canonical basis of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ :

$$u_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;u_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;u_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

and suppose $\;a=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix}\;$ , so that

$$\begin{align*}&Au_1:=a_1a+(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^3)\,u_1=\begin{pmatrix}2a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2\\a_1a_2\\a_1a_3\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
&Au_2:=a_2a+(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^3)\,u_2=\begin{pmatrix}a_1a_2\\a_1^2+2a_2^2+a_3^2\\a_2a_3\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
&Au_3:=a_3a+(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^3)\,u_3=\begin{pmatrix}a_1a_3\\a_2a_3\\a_1^2+a_2^2+2a_3^2\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$

From the above, the matrix representation of $\;A\;$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}2a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2&a_1a_2&a_1a_3\\
a_1a_2&a_1^2+2a_2^2+a_3^2&a_2a_3\\
a_1a_3&a_2a_3&a_1^2+a_2^2+2a_3^2\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, clearly the matrix is symmetrix (and so is $\;A\;$ ), and its prinicpal minors are

$$\begin{align*}A_{11}=2a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2\ge0\\{}\\A_{22}=(2a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)(a_1^2+2a_2^2+a_3^2)-(a_1a_2)^2=\\
=(\text{sum of products of squares})+5a_1^2a_2^2-a_1^2a_2^2\ge 0\end{align*}$$

I leave it to you to check the minor $\;A_{33}=\det A\;$ is also non-negative, and thus $\;A\;$ is indefinite positive.

Or directly, for any $\;x^t=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\Bbb R^3\;$:

$$x^tAx=(x_1\;x_2\;x_3)\left((a\cdot x)a+||a||^2 x\right)=$$

$$=(x_1\;x_2\;x_3)\begin{pmatrix}(2a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)x_1+a_1a_2x_2+a_1a_3x_3\\
a_1a_2x_1+(a_1^2+2a_2^2+a_3^2)x_2+a_2a_3x_3\\
a_1a_3x_1+a_2a_3x_2+(a_1^2+a_2^2+2a_3^2)x_3\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=(2a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)x_1^2+a_1a_2x_1x_2+a_1a_3x_1x_3+
a_1a_2x_1x_2+(a_1^2+2a_2^2+a_3^2)x_2^2+a_2a_3x_2x_3+
a_1a_3x_1x_3+a_2a_3x_2x_3+(a_1^2+a_2^2+2a_3^2)x_3^2$$

Continuing this seems it is going to get annoyingly ugly and messy, but in fact life is pretty:

$$=(2a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)x_1^2+2a_1a_2x_1x_2+
(a_1^2+2a_2^2+a_3^2)x_2^2+2a_2a_3x_2x_3+
2a_1a_3x_1x_3+(a_1^2+a_2^2+2a_3^2)x_3^2=$$

$$=(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)^2+(a_1x_1+a_3x_3)^2+(a_2x_2+a_3x_3)^2\ge 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Checking symmetry of $A$:
$$
( y,Ax)= ( y,(a \cdot x)a+ |a|^2x)=(a\cdot x)(a\cdot y)+\lvert a\rvert^2(x,y)=( x,Ay)=(Ay,x).
$$
Hence $A$ is indeed symmetric.

Positive definite
$$
( x,Ax)=(a\cdot x)^2+\lvert a\rvert^2(x,x)\ge \lvert a\rvert^2\lvert x\rvert^2,
$$
hence it is non-negative definite, and if $a\ne 0$, it is positive definite.